# How to calculate free disk space?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on an installer project where I need to extract files to the disk. How can I calculate/find the disk space available on hard disk using c#?

Comment: You cannot calculate disk space using C#. You'll have to use .NET.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.totalfreespace.aspx

Copied from the link

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("  File type: {0}", d.DriveType);
            if (d.IsReady == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes", 
                    d.AvailableFreeSpace);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes",
                    d.TotalFreeSpace);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes ",
                    d.TotalSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the `System.IO.DriveInfo` class. There are two options available...one that takes disk quotas into account:

```
var drive = new DriveInfo("c");
long freeSpaceInBytes = drive.AvailableFreeSpace;
```

and one that simply provides the total free space:

```
var drive = new DriveInfo("c");
long freeSpaceInBytes = drive.TotalFreeSpace;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use WMI.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Management;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var moCollection = new ManagementClass("Win32_LogicalDisk").GetInstances();

        foreach (var mo in moCollection)
        {
            if (mo["DeviceID"] != null && mo["DriveType"] != null && mo["Size"] != null && mo["FreeSpace"] != null)
            {
                // DriveType 3 = "Local Disk"
                if (Convert.ToInt32(mo["DriveType"]) == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", mo["DeviceID"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Size {0} bytes", mo["Size"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Free {0} bytes", mo["FreeSpace"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to care? Just write the files to the disk and handle the errors as needed - it's assumed that you'll have to implement rollback anyways in case something non space-related happens, so just treat "no disk space" as just another error that you need to rollback for.

**Update:** If you're coming here to downvote this correct answer, please leave a comment as to why.

Comment: Rather sloppy approach, don't you think? Getting available drive space ahead of time is a rather trivial matter, and it can save the user a lot of hassle when installing a program.

Comment: I agree you should warn that the write will be impossibly but you'd still need to handle the drive running out of space during the copy.

Comment: I don't think it's sloppy at all, and it's far worse when a program estimates wrong - there's two answers on this thread and so far, neither of them are complete. Not to mention, what if you have to install some files on the system drive and some in the drive they asked for? How do you explain *that* to the user?

Comment: i think it would still be nice that a user is informed about the remaining free space rather than throwing an error during the installation process. Rollback consumes time, so why go for installation when you can prevent that before it happens?

Comment: Wow, this answer is in need for a compensation upvote.  We are running multitasking operating systems these days folks.  +1.

Comment: While he is right about not calculating the disk space and countering errors in certain cases, the original question asked how to calculate disk space and not should you and therefore he is down voted for not contributing to the conversation.

Comment: @MichaelHohlios I'm helping the OP far more by telling him the right way to solve his problem, rather than informing him the right way to do something wrong.

Comment: this is very good answer, [example] if free space was 1 GB before the data extraction which would require 500 MB, other running  processes might consume part of the storage [like user copying 700 MB from USB..etc] which make calculations false. even windows built in copy feature got to rollback in similar cases. so please think wisely before down voting!!! if you are doing crucial disk operation then you should monitor the status periodically until the task done, yet as for storage size nothing can be done unless OS is single task! otherwise share your ideas.

Comment: Yes, you should care.  Of course, rollback is part of a good installer and if disk space is consumed by another process during the install you should handle it.  But you absolutely care... checking free space in the very beginning and informing the user is much better than allowing an installer to spend a lot of time extracting files only to die then.  Checking at the beginning isn't a guarantee that it will succeed but from a usability perspective you should make an effort to tell your user about issues as early as possible.

Comment: Production-quality systems need to frequently query things like this and notify operations staff so that they can take action BEFORE issues that affect end-users occur.  Would you be recommending this approach for a database server serving hundreds of thousands of requests per second?  When a system like that runs out of space, the entire system abruptly stops until someone fixes the problem.