# What is the best way to determine max amount of threads for C# IO operations based on the system's hard drive?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.5

I've got a tool that will run multiple threads at once that will perform a simple IO operation. The question I have is; What is the best way to determine the max amount of possible threads, based on the system's hard drive capabilities, for IO operations?

Comment: I think you're wanting Environment.ProcessorCount

Comment: @Shar1er80 - That was my first thought too.  But if the bottle neck is the hard drive then a different approach may be warranted.

Comment: Then perhaps a combination of Environment.ProcessorCount and DriveInfo class (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210010/how-to-calculate-free-disk-space)

Comment: ProcessorCount has nothing to do with HDD capacity whatsoever. It should not be in any solution.

Comment: A dynamic approach might be the best way to go, though not the easiest; when it stops getting faster you've reached the point where it won't get faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the OS really 'knows' what kind (HDD/SDD) of drive you have.

It might be possible to find out about RAID configurations through WMI but I'm not sure if that is reliable (some RAIDs are fully implemented in hardware).

And even if you know about your drive, there might be other processes using it.

So some experimentation is required, and probing if you want to do this on multiple machines you can't measure upfront.

Comment: When you mean to recursively scan the disk, I don't really know. Do some tests with 1-4 threads and make it configurable. Be aware that measuring this is difficult due to the caching of the first run. You'll need a restart in between.