# How to check the minimum amount of free disk space C#

Tags: c#

I am creating an installer/uninstaller but I want to make something like

```
if(disk.c.freespace == 750mb)
  {
  continue my program stuff
  }
else
  {
  this.text = ("Error!")
  }
```

If anyone knows how to do it please send it because i cant find the solution anywhere

Comment: [DriveInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.-ctor)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210010/how-to-calculate-free-disk-space & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465187/get-available-disk-free-space-for-a-given-path-on-windows & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393711/get-free-disk-space

Comment: After seeing in details these answers they indicate `GetDrives` for most. Here you can directly use `GetDrive(driveNamePath)`. No need to get all and loop.

Comment: And 750 MiB (MiB I suppose, neither Mib nor MB nor Mb) = 750 * 1024 * 1024. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft .NET documentation - DriveInfo.AvailableFreeSpace Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.availablefreespace?view=netcore-3.1)

You better use using System.IO namespace

```
using System.IO;
```

Inside main

```
       DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
       // get the correct hard drive
        for(int i = 0; i < allDrives.Length; i++)
        {
            if (allDrives[i].Name == "C:\\")
            {
                if (ConvertBytesToMegabytes(allDrives[i].TotalFreeSpace) == 750)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Success");
                } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error");
                }
            }
        }
```

The implementation of ConvertBytesToMegabytes

```
static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
    {
        return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
    }
```

Comment: `var driveC = new DriveInfo("C");`

Comment: lemme see if it works

Comment: Returns an error even tho i have over 30gb left on all drives

Comment: You cannot make this kind of comparison with a double value: `if (ConvertBytesToMegabytes(allDrives[i].TotalFreeSpace) == 750)`. Change it to `>=` at least.

Comment: Returns success at 750mb and error when i make it 75gb, works as a charm, thanks man

Comment: @julianpoelmann: If this successfully answers your question, be sure to mark it as the answer.